# How to use monitors that connected to Mac mini as external monitor for Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, mac-mini, displayport

I have 2 monitors for my Mac mini at home, and recently I decided to buy a new Macbook m1. The problem is if I want to use those 2 monitors as external monitors for my Macbook, I have to unplug the cables from the Mac mini and plug them into my Macbook. Is there some kind of cable or software so I switch my monitors to use signals from my mac mini to MacBook and vice versa, without plugging and unplugging way too munch? Thank you

Comment: You can't connect 2 monitors to an M1 machine, unless its an M1 Pro or Max.

Comment: *Most* monitors have multiple video inputs that are easily switchable using the monitor's controls. I currently use this method to switch between a mini and a MacBook.

Answer (score 1):

You want a KVM (keyboard, video and mouse) switch.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch

These are used to quickly switch peripherals between two computers.